# Parsing a datetime column to a particular format and saving to CSV

Tags: python, pandas, csv, datetime, dataframe

I'm new to python and trying to parse csv and datetime.

I have a csv in the following format -

```
Column-1      Column-2
Name1         03/09/2012 11:26:08
Name2         04/10/2011 11:26:08
Name3         13/11/2010 11:26:08
...           ...
```

I want to parse this csv -> read column2 -> extract only month-year -> store back in the same column and row

I'm able to parse the csv, read the data, extract month-year, but not sure how identify the same row and store it back.

basically the output should be that the same csv is modified to -

```
Column-1      Column-2
Name1         09/2012
Name2         10/2011
Name3         11/2010
...           ...
```

Comment: Could you show your code to extract month-year

Comment: You're not going to be able to modify the file in place. Write the modified data to a new file (and then copy it over the original, if desired).

Comment: Do you have pandas?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Yes, I have pandas

Comment: You don't identify the row. You write a new file, with the same or different name. The only issue comes if you're using `dropna()` if you don't want to lose rows

Answer (score 1):

You add a `parse_dates` parameter when reading your CSV, and then convert to your desired format using `.dt.strftime`.

```
df = pd.read_csv(...., sep='\s{2,}', engine='python', 
                           parse_dates=['Column-2'], dayfirst=True)
df['Column-2'] = df['Column-2'].dt.strftime('%m/%Y')
df

  Column-1 Column-2
0    Name1  09/2012
1    Name2  10/2011
2    Name3  11/2010

df.to_csv(..., sep='\t')
```

Note that, since your dates have the format `DD/MM/YYYY`, an additional `dayfirst=True` parameter must be passed.

Comment: I feel dumb. What is that `sep`?

Comment: @roganjosh Separator for columns, specified as a regex. I don't want to do `delim_whitespace=True` because it might incorrectly split the date column.

Comment: I understand it's for separator but I couldn't make sense of what it does. So it's just for separating on 2 or more consecutive blocks of whitespace?

Comment: @roganjosh Correct. It's entirely possible OP's file is a TSV, in which case `sep='\t'` would be more appropriate. I just took a guess this way.

Comment: At some point I'll learn regex. For now it always looks completely alien :)